# How to enter only an integer value in TextInput with type="number"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use material-UI TextInput to enter only integer values (not decimal values).
I used the TextInput as follows, but it still allows the decimal number.

How can I do that?

```
<TextField id="outlined-value" 
           type="number"
           label="Value" 
           className={classes.standartInputMargin}
           value={this.state.allowedValue}
           margin="normal" 
           variant="outlined"
           onChange={(event) => Number.isInteger(event.target.value) 
               ? this.setState({ allowedValue: event.target.value }) 
               : null} />
```

Comment: use converted value in `setState`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the raw value to `setState`, rather than the integer value. Since your input only accepts numbers, you can just check for decimal places.

```
onChange = (e) => {
  const { value } = e.target;

  if (value.match('.')) { 
    this.setState({ value: parseInt(value) })
  } 

  return null;
}
```

Alternatively, if you just have a regular input, something like this would only allow you to enter integers.

```
onChange = e => {
  const { value } = e.target;
  const parsedInt = parseInt(value);

  if (parsedInt) {
    this.setState({ value: parsedInt });
  }

  return null;
};
```

Comment: This will reject an input of `0`, which may not be what you want. You can use `Number.isFinite(parsedInt)` instead.

Comment: @AndreaReina are you sure? Can't seem to replicate here: https://codesandbox.io/s/l20v65z129

Comment: It accepts an initial value of `0` because that doesn't go through the change handler. Try setting it to another number then back to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
const setValueHandler = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
  }
```

Comment: Need to remove type="Number" from TextField for this.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way i think is to parse value in onChange method.

```
const NON_DIGIT = '/[^\d]/g';
...
onChange(event) {
    const { value } = event.target;
    const intValue = parseInt(value.toString().replace(NON_DIGIT, ''));

    this.setState({ value: intValue });
}
```